# How can I change xctool destination in Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci, xctest, xctool

The fail build is https://travis-ci.org/WilliamZang/FastAnimationWithPOP/jobs/30449252

I've no idea why it is fail.

I try the build `xctool -workspace FastAnimationWithPop.xcworkspace -scheme FastAnimationWithPopDemo -sdk iphonesimulator build test`, it's the same result.

I find the solution is add a arg '-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone Retina (4-inch)"', it make my building success. But I don't know why it works and how to add this arg to travis.yml.

I know the reason is 'xctool -workspace FastAnimationWithPop.xcworkspace -scheme FastAnimationWithPopDemo -sdk iphonesimulator build test' only open the iphonesimulator 6. Even I specify iphonesimulator7.1 it still use iphonesimulator6. I don't know why it always use simulator 6.

It tastes me about 1 day, who can save me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this to add the `-destination` flag to your xctool call (in the .travis.yml):

```
xctool_args: -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone Retine (4-inch)"
```

We automatically launch the simulator at the start of the build, and it sounds like we might be starting an old simulator.